# How to make Glitch/Static Effect Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, effect

I'm trying to make that effect, but I don't know how or the name
Of the effect?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not "an effect" but could be accomplished a few different ways. If it were me I'd look into Core Image filters (CIFIlters). If you've never used them, start with this Apple example:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/CIFunHouse/Introduction/Intro.html

Then look into changing the size and position of the type, applying pixellation and maybe a bit of blur.